# What's wrong here? (Comparing an exit code)

Tags: linux, bash

I want to compare the exit code of a program to an argument. This is what I'm doing:

```
CODE=$1
if [[ $(./program) -eq $CODE ]]; then
    echo "same"
else
    echo "different"
fi
```

Where `$1` gets `"1"`. But I'm getting an error. What's wrong here?

Comment: What's the error?  Try ./program

Comment: You're not comparing exit code, you're just comparing output from `program`

Comment: Aside: Use lower-case names for your own variables -- variable names with meaning to the shell or operating system have all-caps names, so by using all-caps names yourself, you risk overwriting them by mistake (particularly since setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable). See [relevant standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not comparing the exit code; you're comparing the standard output of the program with `$CODE`.

Maybe:

```
CODE="$1"
./program
rc=$?
if [[ "$rc" -eq "$CODE" ]]
then echo "same"
else echo "different"
fi
```

You could just use `$?` in the condition, but you might want it for reporting and validation:

```
CODE="$1"
./program
rc=$?
if [[ "$rc" -eq "$CODE" ]]
then echo "same ($rc and $CODE)"
else echo "different (got $rc, wanted $CODE)"
fi
```

Comment: What if I also need to play with the output of the program? Just execute twice? How you showed me and also `res=$(./program)` ?

Comment: @UFCInsider, `program_output=$(./program); program_rc=$?`

Comment: ...aside: I actually do recommend putting the exit status capture on the same line as the program's execution (as with `;`, vs a newline) -- that way it's clear what it's associated with, and folks adding logging or such to your program in the future are less likely to put more content between the two commands and thereby introduce bugs (ie. capturing the log command's exit status, vs the actual one).

Comment: Ok so I have another problem... I'm actually using `program_output=$(echo "input" | ./program | sed ...); program_rc=$?` but sometimes I get a wrong exit code (although normal running returns a correct one)

Comment: So, `./program` reads its standard input and sometimes exits with a correct exit code and sometimes with an incorrect exit code?  Is `input` a simple string, or does it contain newlines, etc?  Is `program` under your control?  Do you have its source? Does it have any debugging tools built in?  Can you reproduce when the incorrect exit status occurs?  Have you run with `bash -x script.sh` to see exactly what's being executed?

Comment: It's a simple one line string. The program is a code in C that I can't change but I do have its source. No debugging tools built in. I don't quite get what you mean by reproduce. Yes I did, but it just shows the incorrect exit code while the other things look ok

Comment: In this context, 'reproduce' means "can you make the incorrect exit status occur reliably"?  Are you providing the same input string each time?  Presumably not.  Which strings produce the incorrect exit status?  What do they have in common?  If you have the source, you could consider modifying it temporarily to add debugging so you can see from the inside why the program goes wrong.  There must be a reason why the program objects to the inputs it doesn't like.  _[…more information — need a new comment…]_

Comment: I'm tolerably sure you didn't have a `| sed` in your command when I first looked at your comment and responded.  The presence of `sed` complicates things.  You get the exit status from `sed` by default, not the status from `program`. Assuming you're using Bash, you can only get the exit status from `program` if `sed` worked OK (exits with status 0) and if you turn on that behaviour with [`set -o pipefail`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin).

Comment: Oops. So can I get the exit code first, and then use sed on the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130263/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-ufc-insider).

Comment: Amazing help by @JonathanLeffler! Thank you so much!